# Application of intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and $f^\prime(a)$ exists. Let $\xi$ be a number such that $$f^\prime(a) > \xi > \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$ Prove that there is a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $$\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}=\xi$$

I try to use Intermediate Value Theorem to show this. I let $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. I try to show this function is continuous on $[a,b]$ but I don know how to show it continuous at endpoint.

Comment: Are we just assuming that inequality is valid, then? Or do we want to take a $\xi$ between $f'(a)$ and $\frac{ f(b)-f(a) }{ b-a }$ regardless of which side it falls on? Also, $g(x)$ is not defined at $a$, but at $b$ it is the quotient of continuous functions at $b$, so it is continuous at $b$.

Comment: Ignore the thing about $g(x)$ not defined at $a$. In general $f'(x)$ is not continuous, and you don't know much about $f$, so it seems unlikely that you can go that way. You might not need to show that it is continuous at $a$, though; maybe $\frac12(\xi+a)$ will be enough?

Comment: @Eric $\frac12(\xi + a)$ is a bit strange to consider, since $\xi$ is not guaranteed to be in $[a,b]$ at all. So $g$ may not even be defined at that value.

Comment: @EricStucky Sorry but $g$ **IS** continuous, always, and I do not understand the suggestion with $\frac12(\xi+a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that the mapping:

$$h(x) := \begin{cases}g(x) &: x \ne a \\ f'(a) &: x = a\end{cases}$$

is continuous on $[a,b]$. Thus we can apply the IVT to $h$; I presume you can take it from there.

Comment: It seems like his difficulty came from trying to show that $f'(x)$ was continuous at $a$.

Comment: @Eric: $f'(x)$ needn't be continuous. $h(x) \ne f'(x)$ needn't hold for $x \ne a$. For $h$, the very existence of $f'(a)$ assures continuity.